# Native spherical (WGS84) coordinates?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,

I'm looking to build a simulation where I can *accurately* bookkeep my robots position in geodetic coordinates (WGS84 datum).

Unfortunately the ROS+Gazebo+Hector GPS plugin route isn't likely to work, exactly because I'm trying to simulate vehicles at high latitude (near the poles), and traveling large distances *O*(10 km).

Is it possible for Gazebo to run a simulation natively in spherical coordinates? I haven't been able to find any resources to date on this.

If not, have any others found themselves in a similar situation? Outside of writing a dynamical model in MATLAB or similar, have others found an acceptable solution?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13555/native-spherical-(wgs84)-coordinates?/) by [laughlin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2650/laughlin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Take a look at Gazebo's [spherical coordinate class](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e071428f4891f02ff95188d6089a246d2aa0cc8b/gazebo/common/SphericalCoordinates.hh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), and the [GPS Sensor which makes use of it](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/e071428f4891f02ff95188d6089a246d2aa0cc8b/gazebo/sensors/GpsSensor.hh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [laughlin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2650/laughlin/) on 2016-06-07**:
Thanks @nkoenig.

So if I understand correctly, underlying cord sys is still XYZ, but Spherical Coord. class implements proper WGS84<-->local XYZ (via intermediate ECEF frame), with local XYZ origin at the lat/long specified in world file (as defined here: http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.6&elem=world#world_spherical_coordinates). Local XYZ is in an ENU orientation.

Does this sound correct?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2016-06-07**:
That is correct.

**Comment by [laughlin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2650/laughlin/) on 2016-06-08**:
Thank you.